# django-select2: howto add a functionname to templateSelection option without quotes?

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

i would like to use a the templateSelection option provided by select2.

When adding it to the select_2options list it is renderd with quotes.

```
invited_user=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
       required=True, 
       widget=Select2MultipleWidget(select2_options={
            'templateSelection': 'testformation',
            }))
```

this returns:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
     var hashedSelector = "#" + 
    "id_invited_user";$(hashedSelector).select2({
       "templateSelection": "testformation"}
     );
 });
```

with the quotes it is not detected as js function and therefore it is not working.

Can anyone help me to get this to work?

Comment: Any idea if `django-select2` even supports Select2 4.0.0? I'm pretty sure it's still stuck on Select2 3.5.2.

Comment: mhm . i think you are right. I didn't get it to work, so i have removed the fields and added the JS Code manually.